# In M: how do I bind (not join) two tables together?

Tags: powerbi, m

All the M built-in functions assume there is a "key" (and only one key ) by which you want to join two tables. The exception is `Table.Combine()` which combines those columns having the same name.

I want to simply bind the tables together, renaming columns as necessary to avoid clashes where the same names appear in both tables. Where the two tables have different numbers of rows I want to fill the missing rows - of the short table - with a user-defined value or `null`.

How would I do this?

Comment: What is your data source? M can join on more than one key https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-join

Comment: You are correct! (Although there is nothing in the documentation to suggest this). The first result that comes up when you do a google search for "join by multiple columns" is a Microsoft forum post where they state this is not possible and go into the usual hack of merging the columns that constitute the composite key. I will attempt to update that thread because I'm sure others will continue with that hack.

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways to do this in M but can you provide example tables and desired result for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

The R function `cbind()` provides functionality that is similar to what is being described, so in Power BI I've named my query "cbind". R isn't bothered by multiple columns having the same name but M is, hence the use of a prefix to disambiguate the columns. The prefix should be able to be provided as an optional argument; my prefix variable names are anticipating dealing with these nullable arguments. `Table.FromColumns()` doesn't allow the user to specify a value to fill in the spaces, so `null` it is.

```
(table1 as table, table2 as table) =>
let
    Prefix1NoNull = "a.",
    Prefix2NoNull = "b.",
    CommonColumns = List.Intersect({Table.ColumnNames(table1), Table.ColumnNames(table2)}),
    Table1Names = List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(table1), each if List.Contains(CommonColumns, _) then Prefix1NoNull & _ else _),
    Table2Names = List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(table2), each if List.Contains(CommonColumns, _) then Prefix2NoNull & _ else _),
    Result = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(table1) & Table.ToColumns(table2), Table1Names & Table2Names)
in
    Result
```

Comment: Doing it in R in Power Query will require the use of a personal gateway when connecting to the PBI Service for refreshing

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by turning the tables into columns and joining them back into one bigger table.

Use `Table.FromColumns` and `Table.ToColumns` along with some column name functions and `List.Combine`.

[Power Query Table Functions Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-functions)

```
= Table.FromColumns(
      List.Combine(
          {
           Table.ToColumns(Table1),
           Table.ToColumns(Table2)
          }
      ), 
      List.Combine(
          {
           Table.ColumnNames(Table1),
           Table.ColumnNames(Table.TransformColumnNames(Table2, each _ & ".2"))
          }
      )
  )
```

I've appended `".2"` to the column names in `Table2` so that they are unique. You can write this to only append if that name also matches one from `Table1` but I didn't want to further clutter things. To do this, use the following transformation:

`each if List.Contains(Table.ColumnNames(Table1), _) then _ & ".2" else _`

Answer (score 0):

The following code does a CBind in Power M:

```
(listoftables, prefixvar) =>
    let
        //Add Index
            AddIndex = List.Transform(listoftables, each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Index")), //Add Index Key to each datapoint
        
        //first column (original list, holds the XY positions, so we rename this column
            //RenameCol = List.Transform(AddIndex, each Table.RenameColumns(_,{{"Column1", "xy"}})),
        //each table with points had a empty record 
            //RemoveExptyRows = List.Transform(RenameCol, each Table.SelectRows(_, each [xy] <> "") ),
        ToTable = Table.FromList(AddIndex,Splitter.SplitByNothing()),
        // Name the dataset
            Added_Index = Table.AddIndexColumn(ToTable, "ColName", 0, 1),
            Changed_Type = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Added_Index,{{"ColName", type text}}),
            prefix = Table.TransformColumns(Changed_Type,{{"ColName", each prefixvar & _ & "_"}}),

        // get the max index per pointset
            max = Table.AddColumn(prefix, "m",  each List.Max(_[Column1][Index])),

       //generate a list that will represent our main column to which we will cbind the others
            maxofmax = List.Max(max[m]),
            l = List.Generate(()=>0, each _ < maxofmax, each _ + 1 ),
            Index_ConvertToTable = Table.FromColumns({l}, 
                                    type table[ Index = Int64.Type ]),

       //Convert to Table with our pointsets to a list, also contains the name of the set! (second column)
                TableRows = Table.ToRows(max)
                , // we will iterate TableRows, to current will reflect to row being interated,
       //Index_ConvertToTable reflects the first state
                JoinTables = List.Accumulate(TableRows,Index_ConvertToTable,(state,current) => 
                let
                    Joined = Table.NestedJoin(state,{"Index"},current{0},{"Index"},"JoinedTableColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
                    ColumnNames1 = List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(current{0}),{"Index"}), //All Column names other than index
                    ColumnNames2 = List.Transform( ColumnNames1, each (current{1}) & _) , //All these columns with a prefix, being the name of the dataset
                    Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Joined,"JoinedTableColumn",ColumnNames1, ColumnNames2) //These columns exanded and renames to the prefix name
                in
                    Expanded //The joined dataset becomes the new state.
                    ),
            ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(JoinTables,{{"Index", Int64.Type}}),
            Sort = Table.Sort(ChangeType,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}})
in Sort
```

I provide a code walkthrough in [this article](https://medium.com/power-m/cbind-in-power-m-power-query-90685376c656). Hope it helps.

Kind regards,
Steve.